# Link or path to resource in code comment

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm curious whether it is possible to add in xcode comment with link to the project resource e.g. .txt file, but with action to show that file when developer taps on this url/path with 'cmd' button. In that way works well all http urls in comments (developer after tap on this url link is redirected to browser).

I would like to have e.g.

```
// Path to related documentation: /Workspace/Project/documentation.txt
func someMethod() {
...
}
```

and if developer click with 'cmd' button on this path he will be redirected to file or file will be opened for him

Comment: maybe [Markup Formatting Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497) is what you looking for

Comment: @Tj3n thanks, but unfortunately this link is not helpful for me